# How to test how many times a function has been called

Tags: python, function

Let's say I have some code that runs a function infinitely like this:

```
def funct():
    print "Hello"

while True:
    funct()
```

Is there a way that I can test how many times the function has been called (**without** using **try** and **except** with a **recursion error** )then perform some more code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slightly more verbose method would be to use a custom decorator to register function calls.

In the example below a `Counter` class is created that contains a class attribute dictionary containing information about how often each function is called

```
class Counter(object):
    counts = {}

    @staticmethod
    def count(func):
        def wrapped(*args,**kwargs):
            if func.__name__ in Counter.counts.keys():
                Counter.counts[func.__name__] += 1
            else:
                Counter.counts[func.__name__] = 1
            return func(*args,**kwargs)
        return wrapped

@Counter.count
def test():
    pass

@Counter.count
def test2():
    test()

@Counter.count
def test3():
    test()
    test2()

for _ in range(4):
    test3()
    test2()
    test()

print Counter.counts
```

This will output:

```
{'test': 16, 'test3': 4, 'test2': 8}
```

Answer (score 4):

Define a function attribute for your function and bump it every time it is called.

```
def funct():
    funct.callCount += 1
    print "Hello"
funct.callCount = 0
```